# В чем различия между single и viewmodel scope в koin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, scope

Я только начал изучать внедрение зависимостей и не понял различий между single и viewmodel скопами в koin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и любой scope его жизненный цикл зависит от контейнера, это может быть Activity или Application. В данном случае singleton живет до тех пор, пока не будет уничтожен процесс (т.е приложение, Application), а viewmodel scope живет соответственно пока жива наша viewmodel. Single будет более долгоживущим.